# Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Unknown function hiera_hash

Tags: puppet

I am getting the below error when I try to do a `puppet run` on a node, for synchronizing ssh puppet module.

I searched for quite a while and found `hiera_hash.rb` presence in `/var/lib/gems/1.9/gems/lib/....functions/`. I also copied `puppet-hiera/functions/*` to the above location.

I tried running `hiera_hash` in puppet master with `puppet apply` command and it worked. So that confirms `hiera_hash` is working fine in puppet master host

I manually logged in to the node and tried hiera_hash and it's not present in that node and error is originating from that node. Why puppet master puppet configurations are not synchronized to all nodes.

I enabled `pluginsync=true` in puppet.conf in all nodes including puppet master. How to fix this issue???

**Error:**

```
Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Unknown function hiera_hash at /etc/puppet/modules/ssh/manifests/init.pp:9
```

Comment: Sounds like either a bad install or bad Puppet code. Can you give information on either?

Comment: Matt, This is the module I installed in foreman https://forge.puppet.com/saz/ssh.... error occuring at init.pp 9

Comment: and what you installed and how?

Comment: Matt, I think you didn't understand the question.. I installed ssh module in puppet master host, logged in to foreman, selected ssh class and executed puppet run in one of my nodes... thats it... after a min, I got the report from that node saying the last puppet run failed because of that error Unknown hiera_hash....

Comment: Matt, I forgot to tell you one more thing... the modulepath I am installing is /etc/puppet/modules... In puppet.conf also, I have the same entry for basemodulepath and modulepath... but when I type puppet config print modulepath, its giving this output... /home/.puppet/modules.....

Comment: How can I change modulepath to /etc/puppet/modules...???
It may be becaouse of this configuration issue that plugins are not getting propogated to nodes

Comment: I should have been more specific: what Puppet did you install and how did you install it?

Comment: puppet 3.0.1.... 
Ubuntu 12.0.4
sudo apt-get install puppet
Ruby 1.9.3 version

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with `puppetlabs/gcc` and I was getting:

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Unknown function ensure_packages at /etc/puppet/environments/KT_Default_Organization_Library_test_2/modules/gcc/manifests/init.pp:17 on node foo.example.com
```

Only then I have noticed "Dependencies" tab on https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/gcc and realized I'm missing `puppetlabs/stdlib`. When downloaded and pushed into Satellite 6 (and added to content view and republished it - I'm not sure how this works in Foreman) it started to work as expected.

Looking into the comment, you are using `saz/ssh`, so according to https://forge.puppet.com/saz/ssh/dependencies you need `puppetlabs/stdlib` and `puppetlabs/concat`.